# Versioning solution for shared web host

Tags: versioning, shared-hosting

I'm building a website with a few volunteer developers located around the world.  We're using a HostGator shared hosting plan, so we get cPanel, FTP, etc. but no on-server versioning.

For good development practices, it'd be nice to have a test version of the site available with a versioning system behind it.  However, we're all on networks behind NATs, so even if we use a centralized versioning system (GitHub, etc.), we still have to pull changes down to a local server (ie. a 192.0.0.x private SQL/HTTP server) for testing between versions.

Are there any (free-preferred) systems available for versioned test sites?  I've been avoiding VPS because of cost and maintenance complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any (free-preferred) systems available for versioned test sites?

Because

- Test site is "site with production code, used in test environment"
- Versioned site is the same object as "versioned code"

**any SCM**, which can be used for managing *some code*, can be used for this task. Web-development **doesn't have** any *remarkable differences* from any other software-development with VCS behind the scene: only build&deploy process have changes, because you

- have to compile nothing in case of Web
- must to deploy to *some destination* in order to run|test|use development's results

Create *local test-environment* (for every developer in team (?) separately), use any SCM (DVCS can be better and easier somehow, maybe) of choice and appropriate *-hooks of your SCM (or handwork) in order to deliver changed code from working space|repository to test site